# Downloading a file async from s3 bucket to local machine using versionId and object key .net core

Tags: c#, amazon-s3, .net-core

I am trying to download a file from an Amazon S3 bucket asynchronously using an object key and version Id, but it is not downloading. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Can anyone please help me on this?

Comment: Hi, what happens when you run this code ? Do you get error ? What is the error ? Would be helpful if you can add details to the error. Welcome to stack overflow.

Comment: In the above code what are the chances that downloadName, versionID and Path can be empty or null. You are not checking for invalid values.

Comment: I ran this code on debugger, and those objects had values. I cannot step over this line (mentioned in the picture and code) because the program stops.

Comment: Can you enclose the entire function into a try catch block and show what the exception is ? Something as follows
```public async Task<FileDownload> DownloadAsync(String path, String versionId = "", String downloadName = "")
        {
           try
           {
              //all the code you have inside the function
           }
          catch(Exception ex)
          {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
          }
```

Comment: I tried this, but I am getting error that says,"not all code paths return a value."

Comment: The program says waiting for local host on the line without try and catch block.

Comment: Can you share the program that can be compiled and run ?

Comment: I resolved this issue. For some reason, the way I did my connection to Amazons3Client wasn't working. When I tried a different way to connect , it worked!